# Textarea not changing width with a media query

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries

http://adamginther.com

The message text area at the bottom of the page will not change width on mobile. I have tried to implement media queries to change the input and width, the input changes it's width but the textarea does not change it's width on mobile. Is there any way to make it so the textarea will be the same width as the input?

Comment: Its changing. Just checked. Send a screenshot.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? I don't understand your comment. I am unable to take a screenshot of how it looks because I have a sticky power button on my iPhone. I am unable to test this on Android because I don't have any Android devices. All I do know is that this does not work on Chrome or Safari on iOS.

Comment: Go to firefox and press ctrl + shift + M. Change the resolution to 320 and see that it is displaying properly or not. If not, send a screenshot from firefox. If working in Firefox and not on iphone, then from the Firefox screenshot, tell us what is not looking proper. I hope you understood now.

Comment: I changed my user agent through Safari and it worked properly. On my iPhone the width of the textfield is smaller than the rest of the fields.

Comment: I think the question is about how to set cols on a texarea according to screen size.